# How can I optimize the arithmetic and conditionals in this for loop?

Tags: c++, optimization

```
for (int i = 0; i < someValue; i += 4) {
  __m64 mmxValue;

  if (i + 3 < someValue) {
      mmxValue = _mm_set_pi16(_buffer[i], _buffer[i + 1], _buffer[i + 2], _buffer[i + 3]);
      // add and use result
  } else if (i + 2 < someValue) {
      mmxValue = _mm_set_pi16(_buffer[i], _buffer[i + 1], _buffer[i + 2], 0);
      // add and use result
  } else if (i + 1 < someValue) {
      mmxValue = _mm_set_pi16(_buffer[i], _buffer[i + 1], 0, 0);
      // add and use result
  } else {
      mmxValue = _mm_set_pi16(_buffer[i], 0, 0, 0);
      // add and use result
  }
}
```

I'm trying to set up mmxValue with up to 4 16-bit signed values that I would then use for an addition in each of the conditions.

I'm wondering if it's possible to re-write this somehow that uses fewer conditions (or none at all) in a way that would be more optimal.

The conditions exist because for values of i >= someValue the index for _buffer is out of range.

Answer (score 2):

A faster loop would be moving by 4 until you get to the last block

```
int i = 0;
while (i <= somevalue-4) {
    mmxValue = _mm_set_pi16(_buffer[i],
                            _buffer[i+1],
                            _buffer[i+2],
                            _buffer[i+3]);
    ... use the the result ...
    i += 4;
}
... handle only last block with conditionals ...
```

Even better of course would be if possible enlarging `_buffer` variable so that it has room for the extra zeros needed for padding.

Comment: _buffer is actually a ring buffer and any thing past somevalue is off the end - so it's tough to make larger. Would it be cheaper to copy somevalue bytes from the ring buffer to a temp array that is the next multiple of four after somevalue?